# Multiple parameters serializing json in rest service

Tags: java, json, rest, wildfly-10

I made a REST-service and I want to send a parameter with a JSON like this:

```
{
   "array":["hola","juan"]
   "name": "hol"
}
```

This is de code I have of the REST service:

```
@Path("RF")
public class Services {


    @Context
    private ServletContext context;

    private String getPath() {
        return context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/ConnectionData");
    }


    private String doErrorMessage(Exception e){
        return "{ \"ERROR\": \""+ e.getMessage() + "\"}" ;
    }


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("test")
    public Response test(ArrayList<String> array, String name) {
        TM tm = new TM(getPath());
        try {
            tm.do(array, name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500).entity(doErrorMessage(e)).build();
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(ingrediente).build();
    }
```

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 2. Please post the ways you've attempted to make it work, this way, you'll learn better. 3. Fix grammar errors in your post.

Comment: You need a single argument, whose type is a class that matches the json structure.

Comment: but that's what i don't want, have to create a new class for that